# Access unnamed arguments in function without stdarg.h in C

Tags: c

i've always been told that when you leave a function definition with empty parentheses for the arguments, the function can accept any number of arguments or unknown number of arguments, but i never seen this being used.

Just out of curiosity i wonder if there is a way to access the arguments passed to a function defined this way.

Just as an example a function that prints the arguments:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void emptyParent()
{
    // print arguments
}

int main(void)
{
    emptyParent(1, 2, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It might be possible if there is a way to compute the offset of the first parameter, which is why you need to start to count varargs from the last named parameter provided, but I don't think it's possible because you need to find out where the function parameters start.

Comment: i never see things like this. how do you think the parameters should be cleaned? by caller or callee? though, you indeed can get the head of the parameter list, if arch is provided.

Comment: In C, a declaration without parameter list is compatible with a definition with any *fixed* number of parameters, but it is explicitly not compatible with a varargs definition. In short, if you have a varargs function, you *must* declare it as a varargs function; otherwise, it is quite possible that the call will not work.

Comment: @KeithThompson @HuStmpHrrr @rici i know this is old-style and should not be used, and a correct way is to use the functionality of `stdarg.h`, the question is just out of curiosity since i've read in several places that empty pharenteses means unknown number of arguments.

Comment: @wallek876: That's not quite what empty parentheses mean. Empty parentheses in a function declaration mean that the number of arguments is not communicated to the caller (more precisely, to the compiler when processing a call), but the required number and types of arguments are determined by the definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a function *definition*:

```
void func() {
    /* ... */
}
```

empty parentheses indicate that the function has no parameters. There is no way to access the parameters simply because there are none.

In a function *declaration*, empty parentheses indicate that the function requires an unspecified but fixed number and type(s) of arguments. In a call, you must pass the correct number and type(s) of arguments specified by the definition; failing to do so has undefined behavior. (Each argument must match the promoted type of the corresponding parameter.) The compiler will not enforce this for you.

In both cases, this is an *old-style* syntax that should not be used in new code. If a function has no parameters, declare and define it with `(void)`. If it has a fixed number of parameters (one or more), declare and define it with a prototype that specifies the type of each parameter, so that the compiler can enforce the correct arguments in calls (and, in some cases, can implicitly convert arguments to the appropriate type).

If it takes a variable number of parameters, you need to use the `, ...` syntax and the `<stdarg.h>` mechanism to access the parameters inside the function. This mechanism requires a final named parameter to start; you cannot declare or define a function like

```
void this_is_invalid(...);
```

There might be ways to simulate this mechanism without using the features provided by the language, but there are no other *portable* ways to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Since parameters and local variables are all allocated on the stack, and supposing the saved registers pushed on the stack for a function call are always the same, you can compute the offset between the first local variable and the first parameter in a function (here `computeOffset`) and re-use this offset in the function with the undefined number of parameters:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int offset;

void computeOffset(int end)
{
    int start;

    offset = &end - &start;
}

void emptyParent()
{
    int *args;

    args = (int *)(&args + offset);
    printf("arg0 = %d\n", args[0]);
    printf("arg1 = %d\n", args[1]);
    printf("arg2 = %d\n", args[2]);
}

int main(void)
{
    computeOffset(0);
    emptyParent(1, 2, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this may not work. parameters aren't necessary to be passed by stack. give a shot http://ideone.com/jssrXL

Comment: I tested and works in my system but you are off by two positions, args[2] is 1, args[3] would be 2 and args[4] 3

Answer (score -1):

Use variable list of arguments as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdarg.h>

void emptyParent(int first, ...)
{
    // print arguments
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, first);
    // print first
    int max = va_arg(ap, int);
    int next = 0;
    while (next != -1) {
        next = va_arg(ap, int);
        // print next
    }
    va_end(ap);
    return 0; // something
}

int main(void)
{
    emptyParent(1, 2, 3, -1); // -1 marks the end of arguments
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But they did ask about doing this *without* `stdarg.h`

Comment: The poster specifically asked (in the question's title) for a solution without `stdarg.h`.

Comment: i think this is a good enough answer, since not using `stdarg.h` doesn't prevent me from copying all these three macros from the header file to the source.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: Why on Earth would you want to do that? Just write `#include <stdarg.h>`. The macro definitions in the system header are non-portable; copying them just means your code will break when ported to another system, or on a later release of the same system.

Comment: @KeithThompson really shouldn't pick it word by word. the question itself has no portable answer, so if it's answered, the solution should be arch dependent anyway. besides, the question itself doesn't seem to make sense, why on earth i want to do something without using standard library? that's as senseless as asking *how can i convert int to float without using casting*.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: `int n = 42; float x = n;`